# Carousal banner caption is overlapping on scrolling the web page?

Tags: html

i am developing website with html,CSS and bootstrap code. carousal caption is overlapping. how to fix it

My code:

```css
#slider{width: 100%;}

.carousel-caption{
    top: 60%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    bottom:initial!important; 
 }

.carousel-caption h5{
    color: yellow;
    font-size: 42px;
    
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
<div id="slider">
   <div id="#headerSlider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#headerSlider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#headerSlider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#headerSlider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  
  
<div class="carousel-item active">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="d-block img-fluid">
<div class="carousel-caption">
    <h5> Grow Your Business </h5>
    
</div>   
   
   </div>
    
<div class="carousel-item">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="d-block img-fluid">
 <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h5> Website And Digital Marketing </h5>
    
</div>   
   

  </div>
   
<div class="carousel-item">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="d-block img-fluid">
 <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h5> Graphic Designing </h5>
    
</div>   
   
</div>
  
  
  </div>
  
   <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#headerSlider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#headerSlider" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div> 
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: _How to fix it_  .... 
what should we fix if you don't show your code?

Comment: sorry, sharing it